# Running Maven with Android

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I just installed Maven on my Mac and want to set up test project. 
I have created project with archetype from here : http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes
Project was created succesfully. But then I went to folder of project and run `mvn clean install android:deploy` which causes `A required class was missing while executing`.

This sample project should work, but it doesn't whats the problem ?

More of error :

```
 Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project my-android-application: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources failed: A required class was missing while executing com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have all the dependancies on you system for Maven to run.  Double check your path, and installation.

Comment: I've checked everything, still same errors.